# Convert a string to a utf8 string

Tags: c#, string, utf-8

I'm trying to convert a string like

```
<Root>á</Root>
```

To it's UTF string representation, like this

```
<Root>Ã¡</Root>
```

(Taken from this page: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode)

But when I issue Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str) I get an array of utf bytes.

How can I convert those bytes to the string representation I'm after?

--

Thanks for pointing that there is no string representation of an utf8 string.

Just to clarify my needs, I have to execute something like this in sql 2008:

```
xmlAuditoria_Alta 
'
<Out>utf8 char: Ã¡</Out>
'
```

This is the only way I found so far to have this stored precedure correctly save the value

```
utf8 char: á
```

That's why I'm trying to convert from `á` to `Ã¡`

Perhaps there's a more correct way to do it

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UTF string representation". `Ã¡` is what happens when you incorrectly parse UTF8 bytes as a single-byte encoding.  _You should not do that_.

Comment: Please use proper API to work with XML...

Comment: For what it is worth, taken at face value the answer to your question is:

    `Encoding _1252 = new Encoding(1252); 
    // or whatever single byte encoding you desire
    byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    string mangledStr = _1252.GetString(utf8);`

But I am positive that you do not ever want to do this!

Answer (score 8):

Your question is based on an erroneous premise.

```
<Root>Ã¡</Root>
```

is not the UTF-8 representation of your string. In fact that string is the UTF-8 bytes re-interpreted in some other single-byte 8 bit character set.

If you want to convert a C# string to UTF-8 then you do indeed write:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)
```

Comment: +1. Also default encoding for XML is UTF-8 already, so there is a good chance that simply saving XML to stream will produce expected result (instead of direct string manipulation).